# linq group by condition followed by a date group

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to group some data without much luck.

I have a list of data

```
 public class TransactionsViewModel
{
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int TransactionTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Transaction Amount")]
    public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Transaction Date")]
    public DateTime TransactionDateTime { get; set; }

}
```

I am wanting to do some grouping on this so I created a couple of classes like

```
  public class BusinessTransaction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }

}
```

So I can group by BusinessName that is simple

```
  var data = from c in transactions
                   group c by c.BusinessName
                   into business
                   select new BusinessTransaction()
                              {
                                  Name = business.Key,



                              };
```

How can I group transactions now by TransactionDateTime.Date? I am wanting to send back to the client a data structure like

```
BusinessName
  28-06-12
     Transaction
     Transaction
   27-06-12
     Transaction
 BusinessName
   28-06-12
      Transaction
```

Comment: Consider changing
`List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }`
to
`IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, Transaction>> Transactions { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
 var data = from c in transactions
            group c by c.BusinessName
            into business
            select new BusinessTransaction
            {
                Name = business.Key,
                Transactions = business.OrderBy(t => t.TransactionDateTime)
                                       .ToList()
            };
```

EDIT: That's all the structure you can support with your current `BusinessTransaction` class. If you wanted to support the grouping directly, you'd have to add another level of nesting in there.

However, using the existing structure the client can always group things themselves:

```
foreach (var business in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(business.Name);
    foreach (var group in business.Transactions
                                  .GroupBy(t => t.TransactionDateTime.Date))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", group.Key);
        foreach (var transaction in group)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    {0}", transaction.Description);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Ah - I'm not sure the example was present when I started answering the question. I've edited to show how it can be done, sort of...

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet. I sending the data as json to the client so I can't use linq. I will create another class and group into that